# Why did my BCC disappear from my Electron Cash wallet?

Tags: electrum, bitcoin-cash

I use electron cash to manage my BCC, I followed the instructions of electrum.org and sent my BTC from my electrum wallet to a new BTC electrum wallet. I waited for the transaction be completed, then I used my old seed now empty of bitcoins to export to the electron cash, and my BCC appeared in my new BCC wallet. I made two small transfers of my BCC to Bittrex and the transaction was ok, at this point everything was ok.

When I do the transaction my electron cash BCC wallet start to synchronize and all the rest of my BCC (ALMOST 90%) in my Electron wallet just disappeared, the BCC wallet shows the last transaction of BTC but nothing about BCC, even the two small transactions of BCC disappeared from the transaction history. Now my BCC wallet is completely empty, what happened? Sounds like some interference between the two blockchains, can someone please help me find my BCC? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go into your Electron Cash "Tools">"Network" settings, uncheck "select server automatically" and choose a "BCC"/"Electron Cash" server.  Electron Cash has a bug where it sometimes connects to the wrong blockchain.

Comment: Thank you! :D I right clicked on one of the bcc servers on the main page and clicked on "Use as server", and it all went through proper.