# Claiming Bitcoin Cash - where did I go wrong?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash

I read multiple guides on how to 'claim' the BitcoinCash I'm apparently entitled to as a BTC holder.  I outline below the steps I took; but at the end of this process my Electron Cash default_wallet shows a 0 mBCC balance.  Please suggest where I might have gone wrong and what I can do about it:

- In Bitcoin-Qt, generate a new receiving address
- Send all my coins to the new receiving address

I started with 1.13BTC.  Now my Bitcoin-Qt wallet shows a balance of 1.129BTC and under 'recent transactions' it shows the Fee for the transaction.  The 'type' is 'Payment to yourself' and the Amount is -0.0023BTC

- From the Transactions tab, I open the Details for this transaction.  It says 'Total debit -1.129BTC, Total credit 1.129BTC, Transaction ID 32...(64-digit hex string)'
- At https://blockchain.info I entered the Transaction ID and see all the details.  I can see 4 Addresses on the Left and 1 Address on the Right (1JC...)
- In Bitcoin-qt I go to Debug > Console and run `dumpprivkey 1JC...` with the full address.  It outputs a private key (50 characters, alpha-numeric)
- I download and run `Electron Cash 2.9.2`, create a new `default_wallet` and 'Import Private Keys' pasting the 50-character private kay from the Bitcoin-Qt Debug output

Electron Cash shows the Public Address (1JC...) in the Addresses tab, with Balance 0, Tx 0

Bitcoin.info says the following about the transaction:

**Inputs and Outputs**

```
Total Input
1.13157047 BTC
Total Output
1.12926194 BTC 
Fees
0.00230853 BTC
```

Comment: You had the 1.129 BTC in the wallet before August 1st? You can verify on blockdozer.com if the address has funds which are unspent (UXTO). Then you should see them in your BCC wallet as well.

Comment: In addition maybe this helps: 
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57607/why-did-my-bcc-disappear-from-my-electron-cash-wallet

Comment: yes, I've had the BTC for over a year.  Blockdozer returns `There are no transactions involving this address.` for my 1JC... address - which is odd?

Comment: changing the Electron Cash server hasn't made a difference

Comment: so do you see the funds in the address  on blockchain.info from before Aug 1st?

Comment: yes, updated the question with this info

Comment: I would suggest you check the funds of your addresses based on the private key entered on the bip39 page in this description: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57422/how-to-sweep-private-extended-key-from-mycellium-into-coinomi-for-bitcoin-cash-c/57971#57971. This also provides an alternative way to sweep your funds. BTW: if the BTC chain shows different info from the BCC one - what is the date of the related transactions which have latest UXTO. This info is missing.

Comment: send my private key info to the website of this guy on github?  Um. No.

Comment: Sure about your concern. That's why you should transfer your BTC before. If you like you can download the bip page. Still the date info is missing as per above to understand the difference between BTC and BCC chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in this step:

> run `dumpprivkey 1JC...`

What I should have done was to run `dumpprivkey` on the

> 4 Addresses on the Left

In the Blockchain.info output - instead of the *receiving* address.

After doing this, and importing the private keys into Electron Cash, I now have my BCH balance available.

Answer (score 1):

You may have gone wrong by exporting the private key of your /new/ wallet. You want to export the private key of the /old/ wallet and import that into Electron Cash. It isn't clear from your description if you got this right, and that would be one explanation.

Comment: I think it's clear from the description of my steps that I ran `dumpprivkey` on the old wallet

Comment: Dan was correct, you dumped the destination key rather than the old keys.  You should move funds to a new address to be safe as that `1JC...` private key has now been copied around.